# How to find out which apps aren't shown on home screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

Somehow my daughters worked out how to remove apps from the homescreen on my iPhone (long press > remove app).

Is there any way to figure out which apps aren't shown on the home screen but still on my phone?

I know I can get a list of all apps in the app library but can't find an easy way to know which aren't present on the homescreen...

Comment: Not sure if this is quite what you are after - but go into App Store, click on the account icon (top right), go into purchased -> My Purchases  .. you can see ones that are on the phone and not on the phone ..

Comment: @MrR - Thanks but not quite, if for example, you remove an app from homescreen, swipe left to the app library and then swipe down to show all the apps in the app library you'll see a list of all apps on your phone including the one just removed. I'd like to know which ones in this list (or shown elsewhere) aren't shown on the homescreen